# How to Integrate Code Inspections of Jetbrains IDE's in Build Process?

Tags: intellij-idea, continuous-integration, phpstorm, static-analysis, jetbrains-ide

In all teams I worked, we were relying on PhpStorms code inspection capabilities to keep the source code clean. The default settings helped a lot to tackle the "standard issues". We simply agreed to only open a pull request if PhpStorm is giving the green check mark for all files.

I know that there are a lot of static code analysis tools out there to do the same, but I was wondering if there is a tool that does exactly the same code inspection as all the Jetbrains IDE's do. I stumbled upon a blog post that shows how to run PhpStorm itself on a server, but it did not cover the legal issues due to licensing.

Anyone knows if this is possible in an elegant way?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run inspections from command line -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-code-inspector.html

Comment: Thanks. But the downvote is quite harsh...

Comment: So .. how can I help you here (with someone else's downvote)? P.S. People  can use Up or Down as they wish -- there is no obligation to provide reasons.